# What is the issue causing the python package SpeechRecognition to not be recognized?

Tags: python, virtualenv, speech-recognition, python-venv

I am using VSCode with Windows 10 OS, and I have created a Python .venv in 3.7.0 with my interpreter also being 3.7.0. I activated my venv, then pip installed SpeechRecognition and PyAudio successfully.

When I created my main.py as follows, 'os' is recognized but 'speech_recognition' is not.

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
```

The error message is `Import "speech_recognition" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports`

*My file directory layout:* 
`myproject/.venv` 
`myproject/main.py`

*Things I have already tried:*

- Updating Pip
- Making Sure Python Venv and Interpreter Versions Match and are compatible with speech_recognition
- My best guess is the issue lies within the installation of pip/python, possibly the file path. I have attempted to troubleshoot this with no luck finding the root cause of the errors.
- Note: this issue is not particular to this package, my machine frequently has issues recognizing imports

Comment: The problem is how you set the env in the vscode. Bottom right corner you can choose which env will run the code, choose the one you created

Answer (score 0):

Mark Kapilyn's worked. It was running on pyenv version of python and switched to my global python and it worked.